# Is it optional to voice the final letter and linking sound?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, phonetics

I am learning English and I like to observe how people say it.

Most of time, I hear "but I" as "buttai", "out of" as "outtof."
In this case, the T is **pronounced**.

However, I also hear when people say "they don't exist", it sounds more like "don nexist" or "they don Exist"(with a clear E sound). The T is **silent**.

Recently, I heard a movie character say "They won't make it out alive",
and it sounds like "They won makkittou alive". There are few things I observed,

1. The T from "won't" is **silent**,
2. The K sound "make" **links** to "it", and T sound from "it" **links** to "out"
3. The T sound from "out" is **silent** and doesn't link to "alive", I can clearly hear "**a**live", not "talive".

So I am very confused about when I should pronounce the final letter, and when I should link it.

I learned from both American and British films, but the example line is from an American TV show.

Comment: Even within Britain or America, different people will pronounce these consonants differently.

Answer (score 7):

The final consonants usually are being pronounced, but through some allomorphs that make them harder to hear.

- "but I": In this case the /t/ is being pronounced as either a [flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flap_consonant) or a [glottal stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop).
- "out of": The /t/ will be pronounced as either a flap or maybe an [unaspirated consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant) /t/.
- "don't exist": The tongue is in the same place for /n/ and /t/. You could say that the /t/ isn't being pronounced, or that it's being assimilated into the /n/, which is more dominant.
- "won't make": this is different from the "don't exist" - the 'n' can easily flow directly into the /e/, but it can't flow into an /m/. I think in this example the /t/ is bring pronounced, but as an [*unreleased stop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release).

  A [stop consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_consonant) is one where the entire vocal tract gets blocked, so that no air can pass through. Making a stop produces two sounds: the sound of blocking the air and of unblocking it. In many words or phrases a series of two stops get joined together so that the blocking of one is pronounced followed by the unblocking of the other. You can hear this in the word *doctor*. You pronounce the blocking of the /k/, the tongue moves while still blocking the air completely, and then you release the air as a /t/.

  In this example the /t/ is being released as a [glottal stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop).
- "make it": the /k/ is definitely being pronounced, but as an unaspirated consonant, so that it sounds somewhat like a /g/.
- "out alive": like "out of", this will be pronounced as an unaspirated /t/ or a flap.

Answer (score 0):

This is an effect that varies in intensity according to the speaker (or even in different registers of the same speaker).  A given word might be pronounced in full in some accents and truncated in others.

One thing to note is that these differences are not normally reflected in the spelling; the exception is that an author may make a point of indicating accent - usually only in quoted speech, although some novels are written entirely "in dialect".  Examples of this:

- He shouted, "We don' wan' your type roun' 'ere!".
- "Ask 'im if 'e's come from t' other side."

This is in contrast to some languages which have formalized blending of words, that is both spoken and written:

- In Gàidhlig, "an"+"fear" becomes "am fear", and "an"+"sneachda" becomes "an t-sneachda".